# How to fetch custom post types with its full data on wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, rss, feed

I used this feed to get custom post types: http://example.com/feed/?post_type=directory_types

But, it is fetching only title, time, author, url, description.

How to fetch all the data like images, tags, taxonomies, custom fields?

Answer (score 1):

During the creation of the custom post, did you add the support?

'support' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),

Comment: I don't know because am using theme which bought from themeforest

Comment: Then contact theme support team. Let me know the theme you are using.